# Unable to return value from nested function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, return-value, nested-loops

Hey guys i prepare a project with html5 geolocation that will calculate the distance. I've got a problem with returning value from nested function in Javascript, can anyone help me ?

Here is my code:

```
/* DISTANCE CALCULATOR FUNCTION */

function distanceCalc(latitudeB,longitudeB) {
  var result;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    calc(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
  } 

  function calc(latitudeA,longitudeA) {
    var lat1 = latitudeA;
    var lon1 = longitude;
    var lat2 = latitudeB;
    var lon2 = longitudeB;
    var R = 6371; // km  
    var dLat = (lat2-lat1)*Math.PI/180;  
    var dLon = (lon2-lon1)*Math.PI/180;   
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +  
    Math.cos(lat1*Math.PI/180) * Math.cos(lat2*Math.PI/180) *   
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);   
    var c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));   
    var d = R * c;
    result = d.toFixed(1);
    return result;
  }

  return result;

}
```

I would like to do something like

```
var test = distanceCalc(44.35678,33.78546);
```

This code doesnt work, returns NAN value

Comment: The problem is not related to returning the value.

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger and see what happens?

Comment: Side note: Applying correct indentation can make your life much easier.

Comment: I'm really not sure which bit of code you are talking about, but you've got functions which don't have return values, functions which are asynchronous, and functions which expect arguments being called without any.

Comment: Oriol ,where is the problem?

Comment: @billo you call `return showPosition();` without a position argument.

Comment: @mbillard i know there is the mistake, but there is a way to return the value i want with the right way

Comment: In your calc() I'm not seeing where you defined laA, loA, laB, loB.. There for undefined -undefined * something =NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's so many errors on your script and logic. Also, when getting geolocation coords a assync call is made.
Try it out:

```
var DistanceCalc = function(latitudeB, longitudeB, onReadyCallback) {   
    this.latitudeB  = latitudeB;
    this.longitudeB = longitudeB;
    this.callback  = onReadyCallback;

    //calling this.calc() here is ok...
};

DistanceCalc.prototype.calc = function()
{
    var __calc = function(position) {       
        var lat1 = position.coords.latitude;
        var lon1 =  position.coords.longitude;
        var lat2 = this.latitudeB;
        var lon2 = this.longitudeB;

        var R = 6371; // km  
        var dLat = (lat2-lat1)*Math.PI/180;  
        var dLon = (lon2-lon1)*Math.PI/180;   
        var a = (
            Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(lat1*Math.PI/180) *
            Math.cos(lat2*Math.PI/180) *
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
        );   
        var c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));   
        var d = R * c;  
        var result = d.toFixed(1);

        this.callback(result);
    }.bind(this); //bind to DistanceCalc object context

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(__calc);
    } else {
        console.log("geolocation is not available");
        this.callback(null);
    }       
};  

function doSomething(result) {
    console.log(">>> ", result);
}

var calculator = new DistanceCalc(44.35678, 33.78546, doSomething);
calculator.calc();
```